# ID not saving in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm a rails newbie and I've run into an issue I can't get beyond.  I've looked all over SO but cannot find an answer that works.  I have an app that allows for user friendships.  That part works just fine.  However I recently added another level to the friendships by placing friends into circles (sort of like Google+).  The problem I'm having is the circle is not saving in the database.  Here's a look at what's happening:

```
Processing by UserFriendshipsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cupb6S+IdrxqSuEqgfqehJh++POHUMQQ9QqbQVrGtHk=", "user_friendship"=>{"circle_id"=>"9", "friend_id"=>"jimbo"}, "commit"=>"Yes, Add Friend"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."profile_name" = 'jimbo'     LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "user_friendships" ("circle_id", "created_at", "friend_id", "state", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["circle_id", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 06 Jan 2013 17:40:30 UTC +00:00], ["friend_id", 2], ["state", "pending"], ["updated_at", Sun, 06 Jan 2013 17:40:30 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "user_friendships" ("circle_id", "created_at", "friend_id", "state", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["circle_id", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 06 Jan 2013 17:40:30 UTC +00:00], ["friend_id", 1], ["state", "requested"], ["updated_at", Sun, 06 Jan 2013 17:40:30 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2]]
```

Here's the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_friendship, method: :post do |f| %>
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.collection_select :circle_id, current_user.circles.all(:order => 'name'), :id, :name %>
</div>
<div class="form form-actions">
  <%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @friend.profile_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Yes, Add Friend", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", profile_path(@friend), class: 'btn' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here are the associations:

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :circle

class Circle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends, through: :user_friendships
```

The circle has already been created before the user reaches the form.  I've added circle_id to the user_friendships table via a migration, so there's a place for the id to save.  For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going wrong here.  There are no errors on the form and the friendship still saves just not the circle.  What could I be doing wrong?

(let me know if you need more info)

**Edit**
Here's the controller action

```
def create
  if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
    @friend = User.where(profile_name: params[:user_friendship][:friend_id]).first
    @user_friendship = UserFriendship.request(current_user, @friend)
    if @user_friendship.new_record?
      flash[:error] = "There was problem creating that friend request."
    else
      flash[:success] = "Friend request sent."
    end
    redirect_to profile_path(@friend)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Friend required"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Here's the user_friendships table:

```
  create_table "user_friendships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "circle_id"
  end

  add_index "user_friendships", ["circle_id"], :name => "index_user_friendships_on_circle_id"
  add_index "user_friendships", ["state"], :name => "index_user_friendships_on_state"
  add_index "user_friendships", ["user_id", "friend_id"], :name => "index_user_friendships_on_user_id_and_friend_id"
```

Here's the request method:

```
  def self.request(user1, user2)
    transaction do
      friendship1 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')
      friendship2 = create!(user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested')

      friendship1.send_request_email
      friendship1
    end
  end
```

Comment: Post the controller action code...

Comment: Post schema.rb for table `user_friendships`. Is id autoincrement set in your database ?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom - controller action added.

Comment: @Rahulgarg - `user_friendships` table added.

Comment: @BenReilly Post the code for `UserFriendship.request(current_user, @friend)`.  From what I see, you're never passing the circle_id anywhere that it might be getting saved... need to see that method...

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom - request method added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to why it doesn't save the `circle_id` is that you never use it.

From the log messages you show us, it comes in as `params[:user_friendship][:circle_id]`

but you never do anything with this.

I'd suggest the following change

```
def self.request(user1, user2, circle)
  transaction do
    friendship1 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending', circle: circle)
    friendship2 = create!(user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested', circle: circle)

    friendship1.send_request_email
    friendship1
  end
end
```

Then pass it in from the controller

Comment: I tried as you suggested but the `circle_id` is still not saving.

Comment: @BenReilly You'll need to tweak the controller action and either lookup the Circle or tweak Matthew's method to using circle_id directly.

Comment: I've tried tweaking the controller but no luck.  Typically I receive an error `Couldn't find Circle without an ID`.  How would I pass in the existing circle in the controller?

Comment: @BenReilly you get an error loading `Circle.find(params[:user_friendship][:circle_id]`?

Comment: @MatthewRudy yes.  After using your code I now get a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)` error.  I'm not sure why that is since the form appears to have all the necessary arguments.

Comment: if you changed the `request` method definition, then you also need to call it `request(@user1, @user2, @circle)`

Comment: sorry to be a pain on this, but now I get `formal argument cannot be an instance variable`.  Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter is got as params[:user_friendship][:circle_id] and check if you are saving circle_id with this parameter. Also check if the circle_id got from the view is an "integer" type.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still get an error `wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)`.